# Second database yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a website on yii2. I need to connect to remote database to fetch products. For local database I do:

```
$query = new Query;

$query->select(['product_sku'])
      ->from('ntc7r_virtuemart_products')
      ->where(['virtuemart_product_id' => $product_id]);
```

But when I try to connect to remote database via code:

```
$query = Yii::$app->db2->createCommand((new \yii\db\Query)->select(['product_sku'])->from('ntc7r_virtuemart_products'))->where(['virtuemart_product_id' => $product_id])->queryAll()
```

i give an error
`Object of class yii\db\Query could not be converted to string`

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: What's the problem???

Comment: `Object of class yii\db\Query could not be converted to string`

Comment: `createCommand((new \yii\db\Query)` here is your problem.

Comment: Yes i know, but i dont understand how to do to work. Can you help me please? Thank you.

Comment: i tried how you say, but now im giving an error: `Calling unknown method: yii\db\Command::select() ` code: `Yii::$app->db2->createCommand()->select(['product_sku'])->from('ntc7r_virtuemart_products')->where(['virtuemart_product_id' => $product_id])->queryAll();`, but if i do without `createCommand()` i give: `Calling unknown method: yii\db\Connection::select()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
   (new Query())->select(['product_sku'])->from('ntc7r_virtuemart_products')->where(['virtuemart_product_id' => $product_id])->all(Yii::$app->db2);
```

Comment: `'PDOStatement::fetchAll() expects at most 3 parameters, 32 given
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `product_sku` FROM `ntc7r_virtuemart_products` WHERE `virtuemart_product_id`=614'` another problem :/

Comment: Can you paste your code now? You need to use ->all() not ->fetchAll() at the end.

Comment: `$query = (new Query())
                ->select(['product_sku'])
                ->from('ntc7r_virtuemart_products')
                ->where(['virtuemart_product_id' => $product_id])
                ->createCommand()
                ->queryAll(Yii::$app->db2);`

Comment: there is no need for  ->createCommand() ->queryAll(Yii::$app->db2)
replace that with ->all(Yii::$app->db2)
`$products = (new Query())->select(['product_sku'])->from('ntc7r_virtuemart_products')->where(['virtuemart_product_id' => $product_id])->all(Yii::$app->db2);`